# REST Best practice for sync log data in reverse order

Tags: rest, api-design

Consider a backend system that stores logs of this form:

```
{"id": 541, "timestamp": 123, "status": "ok"}
{"id": 681, "timestamp": 124, "status": "waiting"}
...
```

Assuming that there are MANY logs, a client (e.g. an Android app) wants to sync the log data stored at a server to the client's device for presentation. Since the most recent logs are of more interest to a user, the GET request should be paged and start with the most recent logs and walk its way towards the oldest ones.

What is a proper design for this situation? What about the following design?

Let the server response in **reverse order**, add parameters `lastReceivedId`and `size` to the request and add a field `more=true/false` in the response that indicates whether there are more old logs available before the oldest log send in the current request. On the first request set `lastRecivedId=-1` indicating that the server should answer with the most recent logs.

Answer (score 0):

Ship 'em all, let the server sort them out. The endpoint simply doesn't care what order they show up in, the server will handle that detail for presentation.

On the client, the client can choose to send the latest logs first, but that's simply coincidence. There's no requirement one way or the other.

There's also no need to send them in any particular order. If the client has a thousand log entries (in chronological order), it can send back batches of 100 starting at 900-1000, then 800-899, etc. The server will figure it out in the end.

Comment: It's meant the otherway round: the server knows the logs and the client wants to present the latest 1000. So we are talking about GET not POST. I fix the question to make it more clear.